# SQL Server 2008R2 Indexes for log table

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to do some logging in my app. Daily payload is about 50000 insertions. I have to store several fields, the most important - event type and event date/time. There gonna be queries with sorting, paging and filtering. What indexes (**on what fields and clustered or non-clusterd**) should I create in order to minify insertions and query time (at least for select .. where on the fields above)? Googling give various ideas on the subjuct so I can't figure out what to do

**UPD**
My POCO:

```
public class LogEntry
{
    public DateTime LoggedAt { get; set; }
    public int EventType { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccesful { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public string UserAgent { get; set; }
}
```

The most frequent query is `select .. where (LoggedAt between .. and ..) and (EventType=..)`. Sometimes there may be additional `and` parts of `where` clause.
Also no update operations are planned. Deletions are possible but only occasionally by lagre bulks.

Comment: Post the **exact** table structure and the **exact** queries you're going to run.

Answer (score 1):

Following statements is only for ilustrate some possible cases. Ofc its difficult to provide you a specific solution (you have to describe your selectivity). But you can see here some points of view and maybe it can help you.

Some rulles that can help you: 
more indexes -> hardest insert
- do best index for majority of selectivity on as much as is possible unique value...

clustered index - replaces your heap by B-Tree

nonclustered index - referencing pages to your heap (creates new object) - consumes more space -> index + data

```
-- your table should seems like :
CREATE TABLE LogEntry (LoggedAt     DATETIME,
                       EventType    INT,
                       IsSuccesful  BIT,
                       Message      VARCHAR(511),--check your input to set it correctly
                       URL          VARCHAR(511),--check your input to set it correctly
                       Login        VARCHAR(127),--check your input to set it correctly
                       IP           VARCHAR(63),--check your input to set it correctly
                       UserAgent    VARCHAR(63))--check your input to set it correctly

-- For examlle for following select
SELECT * 
FROM LogEntry 
WHERE LoggedAt BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE()) AND
      EventType = 1

-- can help following index (ofc unique values is best for clustered indexes)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_LogEntry_LoggedAt_EventType ON dbo.LogEntry (LoggedAt,EventType)

-- For example for following select
SELECT Message 
FROM LogEntry 
WHERE LoggedAt BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE()) AND
      EventType = 1
-- can help following index 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_LogEntry_LoggedAt_EventType ON dbo.LogEntry (LoggedAt,EventType) INCLUDE (Message)

-- and so ... it really depends what you really want...

-- for me can be really helpfull following solution:
CREATE TABLE LogEntryO (LogEntryId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, -- my clustered index
                       LoggedAt     DATETIME,
                       EventType    INT,
                       IsSuccesful  BIT,
                       Message      VARCHAR(511),--check your input to set it correctly
                       URL          VARCHAR(511),--check your input to set it correctly
                       Login        VARCHAR(127),--check your input to set it correctly
                       IP           VARCHAR(63),--check your input to set it correctly
                       UserAgent    VARCHAR(63))--check your input to set it correctly
-- + following index
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_LogEntryO_LoggedAt_EventType ON dbo.LogEntryO (LoggedAt) INCLUDE (LogEntryId)

-- and my query should seems

;WITH CTE AS (SELECT LogEntryId FROM dbo.LogEntryO WHERE LoggedAt BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE()))
SELECT *
FROM dbo.LogEntryO a
JOIN CTE b ON a.LogEntryId = b.LogEntryId
WHERE a.EventType = 1
```

It is really hard to create best solution for you, because it seems that you using c# class for accesing to this table. For example you could using some kind of ORM , for example entity framework or soo...

Comment: thank you for your answer! I use EF Core, it requires primary keys so creating clustered table with Id is option for me I guess. But there are also should be non-clustered indexed. What is the difference between `ON dbo.LogEntryO (LoggedAt, EventType)` and two different indexes `ON dbo.LogEntryO (LoggedAt)` and `ON dbo.LogEntryO (EventType)`? Do I really need to include Id considering the fact that there are no `where Id=..` statements?

Comment: Np, It is index optimal for JOIN CTE b ON a.LogEntryId = b.LogEntryId ... These two indexes covering query bellow... LogEntryId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED - index one and NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_LogEntryO_LoggedAt_EventType ON dbo.LogEntryO (LoggedAt) INCLUDE (LogEntryId) - index two , optimal for selectivity by time in CTE joined to orig table with selectivity by id ... because id is included in this index... - this nonclustered index can contain also event type if you want...

Comment: i mean that this nonclustered index is important for clausule BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE()) and there is fact about non clustered indexes , that if you want use index scan/seek , you have to include columns that are in select statement... Else it will be non optimal index without usage...

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give a specific answers without more information.  Any way, I think you can try using an index with your two most important field.
Remember (but may be you already know it) the order of the field is important with respect the query you do.
If you know that the query is always the same, you can add others filed (in the index or with INCLUDE column).
Evaluate the "cardinality" of the fields value too.
If possible, give often a look at the information MSSQL stores about the use of the index.
If it is a OLTP system, with frequent update/delete, it could be not positive to add too much indexes.